# Is there a way to start Torrential minimized or in the tray?

Tags: startup

I feel it's a bit annoying to minimize the app manually each time I turn my computer on, and i dont want, if there's a person next to me, that they see everything I'm downloading :)

Tried adding --minimized or -m but it didn't worked.

Thank you!

Comment: This might not be a fix for now, but the feature is planned: https://github.com/davidmhewitt/torrential/issues/100

Answer (score 0):

You could try qBittorrent instead.

[image]